# How can I find my wheel size

Tags: wheels

I was wondering if anyone could help me find out what size rear wheel I need to buy as a replacement (wheel is EXTREMELY out of true) as I cant seem to find it.

Bike: REACTION HYBRID HPA PRO 400
Tyres currently on bike: 28 x 1.65 - 700 x 42c

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: I would guess that a 700c wheel would work. Any information on the wheel manufacturer/model?

Comment: The rim is ISO 622 -- its "bead seat diameter" is 622 mm.  The width (from the inside of one flange to the inside of the other) is hard to guess, but likely in the 20-25mm range.  (You can eyeball it pretty well with a ruler against the rim after removing the tire.)

Comment: (Note that there very likely are stickers on the rim which give its size.)

Answer (score 7):

This is actually a [mountain bike](https://www.cube.eu/en/products/e-bike-hardtail/reaction-hybrid/cube-reaction-hybrid-hpa-pro-400-blacknwhite-2016/), despite the name (hybrid referring to having a battery, it seems).

You need a 700c (29", ISO 622) rim with a 135 mm OLD hub (a mountain hub spacing) and mounting for discs (your existing rotors are centerlock, so unless you want to use a different rotor or adapter, you should get a hub with that). [Width compatibility](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#width) is another thing to look for -- very wide tire on very narrow rim and vice versa are not good combinations. The freehub should be compatible with your cassette.

Note that a wheel that looks extremely out of true can often be made to work well with a bit of adjustment -- unless you're sure the wheel is a gonner, I'd try that first.

Comment: In bicycle terms, "hybrid" does not refer to having battery. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_bicycle

Comment: @ojs - I recognize that. But look at the actual bike -- it is a hardtail mountain bike with a battery. Cube uses "hybrid" to denote bicycles with a battery, it seems.

Comment: Ah, I didn't recognize that it's branding effort. "reaction hybrid hpa" etc has a strong BSO sound to it.

Answer (score 4):

The size is 700c, indicated by "700 x 42c." The reference to 28" is in there because a few countries use that designation for the same thing. You also need to match the frame spacing of the bike (135mm if it was made in the last 20 or so years), the brake type (rim versus disc), and freewheel versus cassette rear cogs.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers haven't referenced rim width.

According to this [image]

...your rim width is between 17c and 23/25c.  So you need a 700c wheel with a rim width between 17 and 24.

You also need a freehub that is compatible with the cassette you already have, and either a suitable disk brake rotor mount, or a rim brake track for any rim brakes.